# ruby object model + class creation based on another class

Tags: ruby

my question may be very basic n foolish but i m confused why the output is this way.

```
MyClass = Class.new String
MyClass.ancestors
=> [MyClass, String, ..]

AnotherClass = Class.new MyClass
=> AnotherClass 
AnotherClass.ancestors
=> [AnotherClass, MyClass, String, ..]
```

in the above code, i m creating a new instance of Class named MyClass and have passed the object(everything in ruby is an object) 'String' as the parameter. Why does 'String' occur in the ancestors list for MyClass. I haven't inherited MyClass from String but that's what ruby seems to be doing. It does work as copy constructor but why the inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following

```
class A < B
end
```

is in fact just a syntax sugar for

```
A = Class.new B
```

See [Random Ruby Tricks: Class.new](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-09-09-random-ruby-tricks--class-new) and the [official docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new) for more info.

Comment: thanks. now i get why Object is the default superclass. i thought it might be setting some internal pointer in the cpp code but this is set in Class.new. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't inherited `MyClass` from `String`

Yes you have. That's what [the argument to `Class::new`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-c-new) means:

> ## `new(super_class=Object)` → `a_class`
>
> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or `Object` if no parameter is given).